# A Noetherian domain $R$ is a UFD iff $I_{fg}=\{h\in R \mid hg\in(f)\}$ is principal for all $f,g\in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be Noetherian domain. For $f,g \in R$, define the ideal $I_{fg}=\{h\in R \mid hg\in(f)\}$. Prove $R$ is UFD iff $I_{fg}$ is principal for all $f,g\in R$.

I'm stuck at this problem. The condition for a ring to be UFD on top of my head is Kaplansky's theorem. However I don't think I could make use of that theorem here since it involves considering all prime ideals. Also I don't really know how to make use of $R$ being noetherian. Any ideas to prove this?

Comment: The usual notation for $I_{fg}$ is $(f):g$ and represents the quotient or colon of the two principal ideals.

Comment: If you want to use Kaplansky's Theorem, then some basic Commutative Algebra machinery is needed. First notice that it is enough to show that the prime ideals of height one are principal. Let $\mathfrak p$ be such an ideal, and $0\ne f\in\mathfrak p$. Then $\mathfrak p/(f)$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R/(f)$, so it is associated, that is, there is $\bar g\in R/(f)$ such that $\mathfrak p/(f)=\mathrm{Ann}(\bar g)$. This shows that $\mathfrak p=(f):g$, and therefore $\mathfrak p$ is principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $I_{fg}$ is principal for all $f,g$.

Since $R$ is Noetherian, all elements can be written as a finite product of irreducibles. I.e., $R$ is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_domain).

Now all we need to do is show that irreducibles are prime. Let $f$ be irreducible in $R$. 
Now consider $g\not\in (f)$, and consider $I_{fg}=(h)$. Then we know that $fg\in (f)$ by definition, so $f\in I_{fg}$. Thus $f=hk$ for some $k\in R$. However, $f$ is irreducible, and $h$ is not a unit, because in that case $g$ would be in $(f)$, contradicting our choice of $g$. Thus $f\mid h$. Therefore if $xg\in (f)$, we have that $f\mid h\mid x$, so $x\in (f)$. Thus $f$ is prime.

For the opposite direction, note that if $R$ is a UFD, then $I_{fg}$ is generated by $\operatorname{lcm}(f,g)/g=f/\operatorname{gcd}(f,g)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch.